# How to add additional column with default value in SQL query which actually doesn't exist in the table

Tags: sql-server

I have two database tables which I use to feed the same jquery DataTable. The problem is that the data is very similar (I show information for individual persons and companies) but it differs in that that the individual person has Personal Identification Number(PIN) and the Company has (IBAN). So I need two columns in my jquery DataTable one named `PIN` and one named `IBAN` and each row will have only one of the both field filled and the other will be empty.

So my problem is, due to the fact how I construct my JSON the most easiest way would be to add some fake column to each query like, for the Individual Perosn query :

```
SELECT Name, City, PIN, IBAN(this is the fake column which should be null) FROM Persons
```

and for the Company query :

```
SELECT Name, City, PIN(this time this is a fake column which should be null), IBAN FROM Companies
```

The problem is that I don't know if this is possible, and if it is, how to do it. I have the option to do this later after I fetch the records but like this it would be very easy.

Comment: You can do this `SELECT Column1, Column2, '' AS FakeColumn, Column3 FROM MyTable`

Comment: @DavidG this one is easy and works just fine, if you want post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `select` a fake column quite easily. Just create the value and name it.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, '' AS FakeColumn, Column3 FROM MyTable
```

Or with NULL:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, NULL AS FakeColumn, Column3 FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it like this

```
Declare @IBAN nvarchar(10)=NULL
SELECT Name, City, PIN, @IBAN FROM Persons
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work but `..'' AS IBAN` seems a little bit cleaner.

Comment: yep its your choice both are one and same i think! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using following:

Query for person table:

```
SELECT Name, City, PIN, Null as IBAN FROM Persons
```

Query for Company table:

```
SELECT Name, City, Null as PIN, IBAN FROM Companies
```

Comment: You can replace Null with any default value or variable.

Comment: use individual queries for your purpose then.